# how to store string values like below array values without parenthesis seperated by comma as lattitude & longitude

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery

```
 string locationPoints= "(29.67850809103362, 79.74288940429688),(29.367814384775375, 79.29519653320312),(29.561512529746768, 79.20455932617188),(29.69759650228319, 79.45449829101562)"; /* C# code */

    success: function (data) {   /* javascript code
                var points = [];
                points[0] = [25.1420, 55.1861];
                points[1] = [25.001225, 55.657674];
                points[2] = [25.3995, 55.4796];          .... }
```

Am passing above locationpoints of c# method to jqueryajax success function.
    I need to pass the locationPoints to javascriptMVCArray to draw polygon on map. here i have to store those locationPoints same as above points array. But i don't know that how to store. Please can anyone help me in that.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you have to play a bit with the string. Split by commas, remove extra parenthesis, etc.

```
 var locationPoints= "(29.67850809103362, 79.74288940429688),(29.367814384775375, 79.29519653320312),(29.561512529746768, 79.20455932617188),(29.69759650228319, 79.45449829101562)";

 var getPoints = function(){
   var pairs = locationPoints.split('),');
   var orderedPairs = [];
   pairs[pairs.length-1] = pairs[pairs.length-1].slice(0,-1);
   pairs.forEach(function(pair, index, array){
     array[index] = pair.substring(1);
     var orderedPair = array[index].split(',');
     orderedPairs.push([parseFloat(orderedPair[0]), parseFloat(orderedPair[1])]);
   });

   orderedPairs.forEach(function(pair, index, arr){
      $('#points').append('[' + pair[0] + ', ' + pair[1] + ']<br>');  
   });
 }
```

Here's a plnkr with it
http://plnkr.co/edit/eYEwm84f5By40oYNpHNo?p=preview

Comment: Thanks ZSnake. Now i can able to draw polygons on map.

Answer (score 0):

Just don't use Regex where you don't need to. This is not where you need Regex, so don't go there.
To summarize and clarify: Do not use regular expressions for this.

Some splitting and trimming will do the same work, much faster:

```
                        // First we split by "),(" to get each of the points
var res = locationPoints.Splits(new[]{"),("})

                        // Each point-string will be handled to produce Lat and Lng
                        .Select(pt =>
                               {
                                   // Remove '(' and ')' to clean first/last points
                                   // And split by comma to get the two components
                                   var s = pt.Trim('()').Split(',');

                                   var lat = s[0].Trim();
                                   var lng = s[1].Trim();

                                   // Choose how to represent each point, example:
                                   return new LatLng {Lat=lat, Lng=lng};
                               })
                        // Make an array out of that
                        .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

using regex match we get the solution using simple code,

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace testpro1
{
    class Program
    {
       public string[] poarr = null;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string strRegex = @"([0-9]*\.[0-9]+|[0-9]+)";
            string strTargetString = @"(29.67850809103362, 79.74288940429688),(29.367814384775375, 79.29519653320312),(29.561512529746768, 79.20455932617188),(29.69759650228319, 79.45449829101562)";
            //matches is the array
            Match[] matches = Regex.Matches(strTargetString, strRegex)
                         .Cast<Match>()
                         .ToArray();
            Console.WriteLine("The Array Values are:\n");
            foreach (var item in matches)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item.ToString());
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```